# New to java, unclear on syntax/compiler errors

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a fairly simple program it calculates what larger coins a group of pennies can be turned into (first into quarters, leftovers into dimes, and then leftovers into nickels) I've coded mostly in c++ before so I'm a bit unclear on how java differs. I'm not really sure what the compiler errors mean, and thus far searching has turned up completely different situations with the same error codes.

```
    public class coins
{
   int input = 0;
   int current_pennies = 0;
   int quarters = 0;
   int dimes = 0;
   int nickels = 0;
   int remainder = 0;



   //input is loaded
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the starting number of pennies: ");
   }



import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
input = in.nextInt();


// current pennies is set to input

current_pennies = input;

//quaters is set equal to  current pennies divided by 25 and floored.

quarters = current_pennies / 25;

//current pennies is set to current pennies, modulo 25. IE the remainder.

current_pennies = current_pennies % 25; 

//dimes is set equal to  current pennies divided by 10 and floored.

dimes = current_pennies / 10;
//current pennies is set to current pennies, modulo 10  IE the remainder.

current_pennies = current_pennies % 10; 
//dimes is set equal to  current pennies divided by 5 and floored.

nickels = current_pennies / 5;

//current pennies is set you current pennies, modulo 5  IE the remainder.

current_pennies = current_pennies % 5; 
//outputting the data

public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Number of Quarter s" + quarters);
         System.out.println("Number of Dimes " + dimes);
          System.out.println("Number of Nickels " + nickels);
           System.out.println("Remaining Pennies " + current_pennies);
   }





}
```

and the compiler errors.

```
 ----jGRASP exec: javac -g coins.java
coins.java:19: error: illegal start of type
import java.util.Scanner;
^
coins.java:19: error: <identifier> expected
import java.util.Scanner;
                        ^
coins.java:22: error: <identifier> expected
input = in.nextInt();
     ^
coins.java:27: error: <identifier> expected
current_pennies = input;
               ^
coins.java:31: error: <identifier> expected
quarters = current_pennies / 25;
        ^
coins.java:35: error: <identifier> expected
current_pennies = current_pennies % 25; 
               ^
coins.java:39: error: <identifier> expected
dimes = current_pennies / 10;
     ^
coins.java:42: error: <identifier> expected
current_pennies = current_pennies % 10; 
               ^
coins.java:45: error: <identifier> expected
nickels = current_pennies / 5;
       ^
coins.java:49: error: <identifier> expected
current_pennies = current_pennies % 5; 
               ^
10 errors

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Comment: First thing's first, all imorts go before the line where you define the class

Comment: `import` belongs at the top of the file, after `package` and before `class`. Executable content should reside with a method context

Comment: Second thing, you should make all changes to the value of a variable in the public static void main method in this instance because you have no other methods

Comment: Well, You need to find out a java tutorial online before coming to StackOverflow.

Comment: Looks like you've coded with javascript. Find a book/tutorial on Java.

Comment: Rules are not that much different from c++

Answer (score 1):

All imports go at the top of the file, otherwise, it looks like your programs actual code is correct essentially, all I have done is just removed the redundant initializations of the coin variables to 0 at the top of your class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Coins {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the starting number of pennies: ");
    // TO DO: Add some form input verfication to ensure program does not crash (InputMismatchException) if user enters a alphabet letter etc. 
    int input = scanner.nextInt();

    // int variable currentPennies is set to input
    int currentPennies = input;

    // int variable quarters is set equal to currentPennies divided by 25 and floored.
    int quarters = (int) Math.floor(currentPennies / 25);

    // currentPennies is set to currentPennies modulo 25, i.e. the remainder.
    currentPennies = currentPennies % 25; 

    // int variable dimes is set equal to currentPennies divided by 10 and floored.
    int dimes =  (int) Math.floor(currentPennies / 10);

    // currentPennies is set to currentPennies modulo 10, i.e the remainder.
    currentPennies = currentPennies % 10; 

    // int variable nickels is set equal to currentPennies divided by 5 and floored.
    int nickels = (int) Math.floor(currentPennies / 5);

    // currentPennies is set to currentPennies modulo 5, i.e the remainder.
    currentPennies = currentPennies % 5; 

    // Outputting the number of each type of coins
    System.out.println("Number of Quarters: " + quarters);
    System.out.println("Number of Dimes: " + dimes);
    System.out.println("Number of Nickels: " + nickels);
    System.out.println("Remaining Pennies: " + currentPennies);
  }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Please enter the starting number of pennies:  98
Number of Quarters: 3
Number of Dimes: 2
Number of Nickels: 0
Remaining Pennies: 3
```

Try it **[here](https://repl.it/repls/CarefreeSpatialConditionals)**.

One more thing you might be confused about is the `(int)` on some lines basically this is because of the `Math.floor()` method returning the `double` datatype which if we used would mean either we would get decimal points that don't really make sense in the output, or we would need to specifically format our output so those decimal points were not shown (more work than just casting to `int`).

---

Here are a couple of extensions you could try implementing if you want to challenge yourself:

1. Make the program not crash if the user inputs **a** for the number of pennies they have.
2. Make the program no longer print anything for a coin you will not get back i.e. don't print the `Number of Nickels: 0` line in the example.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put your import, above your class, like below. This is the java structure. first imports and next you write the class that you intend to use the library you import.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class coins
{
   int input = 0;
   int current_pennies = 0;
   int quarters = 0;
   int dimes = 0;
   int nickels = 0;
   int remainder = 0;
}
```

Comment: this isn't an answer. Remove this.

Comment: while not a complete answer, it does solve the first two compiler errors.

Comment: I edited my answer. thanks for reply @NicholasMango